# Can't retrieve image from PHP Mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, view, blob

Good day everybody.

I'm trying to code an android app which should retrieve from a mysql db a blob   and convert it to an imageview on android.

I can succesfully load the image to webserver (XAMPP) encode it to blob and store it in sql table.

greetings to everyone!

public class RequestHandler {

```
public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String result;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(result);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

here the code to retrieve the image:

public class ViewImage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private RequestHandler requestHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.download);

    RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
    buttonGetImage.setOnClickListener(this); }
private void getImage() {
    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ViewImage.this, "Uok..", null,true,true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b) {
            super.onPostExecute(b);
            loading.dismiss();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            String id = params[0];
            String add = "http://192.168.1.121:8080/getImage.php?id="+id;
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(add);
                rh.sendGetRequest(add);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return image;
        }
    }
    GetImage gi = new GetImage();
    gi.execute(id);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getImage();
}
```

}

here the php script:

```
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
  $sql = "select * from image where id = '$id'";
  require_once('dbConnect.php'); 

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 

echo base64_decode($result['image']);

 mysqli_close($con);

}else{
echo "Error";
}
```

Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any exception to show? Is the request processed by the webserver? Is the webserver URL (private net) reachable from the phone? Is the image correct returned of the request is made from the browser?

Comment: Actually there is not any exception to show. It just does not work. I tried to run the php script and it actually worked. it seems that the code does not reach the websever. The address it right. i used same url for login class which actually works.

Comment: debug and check if the inputstream reads any data. to like a byte array. and check the logcat for errors.

Comment: according to logcat:  
D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7ef1d59010 disconnect failed

Comment: @Dev_Wannabe if the code doesn't make it to the server then an error must appear in the logcat;

Comment: i think that i wrongly coded the method -  rh.sendGetRequest(add) - but i don't know how to fix it. 
By the way, that you a lot for your support

Comment: the return value of rh.sendGetRequest(add) is never used so it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: i run the Debug and returned "Cannot find local variable 'image'. it seems the image is null

Comment: @Dev_Wannabe no problem!

Comment: check if any data is actually read from url.openconnection.getinputstream.

Comment: it's not: Image = Cannot find local variable 'image'

Answer (score 0):

```
As we know that, Image parsing we are using Bitmap, or Base64 Ecodder.

I suggest you to use library like Glide, Picasso this is official library...
You don't have to write so much code.  
Avoid to use Boiler Plate Code in Development.

Picasso

    Picasso.get()
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)


Glide

GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("http://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
    .override(300, 200)
    .into(ivImg);
```